# react-native-pell-rich-editor: How to add Audio?

Tags: react-native, audio, textinput

In my React-Native project I need to add audio files in between the text, So my question is How we can insert audio link in the Editor? does react-native-pell-rich-editor supports this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an audio by inserting an audio tag to the html, rich editor works as an WebView component so it will render out the audio tag as in a web page.

You need to add a ref to the RichEditor

```
const richText = React.useRef();

    <RichEditor
              ref={richText}
            />
```

Then using that ref you can add more html to the RichEditor, below is some sample code

```
  const addToHtml = () => {
richText.current?.insertHTML(
  '<source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">',
);
```

};